# How do I split data and split date from a text file?

Tags: ruby, arrays, date, csv, split

I have a CSV data file with following data:

```
id,account_number,balance,date
1,ar161429,482.29,11/28/2007 15:54
2,ar182364,266.93,10/9/2007 15:54
3,ar106644,887.78,10/23/2007 15:54
```

I am trying to create an array for the date and account number, and then break the date down further into day, months and year. I was able to split the data based on "," and create an array for account and date but when I try to the split the date into month and day it is not working. Here's my code:

```
class Account
 puts "Please Enter the name of account file in .txt format"
 balance_file = gets.chomp

 @number_lines = File.read(balance_file).scan(/\n/).count
 @number_lines = @number_lines - 1


 File.open(balance_file) do |aFile|
   @@balance = []
   @@balance_due = []
   @@balance_due_day = []
   @@balance_due_month =[]
   @@balance_due_year = []

   aFile.each_line do |line|
     @@balance << line.split(",").values_at(2)
     @@balance_due << line.split(",").values_at(3)
     puts @@balance_due

   end


   i = 1
   begin
     @@balance_due_day[i] =  @@balance_due[i].split("/").values_at(0)
     @@balance_due_month[i] = @@balance_due[i].slice!(3,2)

     i +=1
   end    while i<@number_lines
 end
end
```

Comment: What version of Ruby? There is a CSV class that  would probably make this a bit easier. See http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html.

Comment: Don't use `@@` variables unless you absolutely know why you should use them. Class variables, like globals, have their place, but injudicious use is usually a sign of not understanding their purpose, and can lead to real problems with unexplained bugs/errors due to them being changed unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, many things to tell:

First, `slice!` ends with `!`, so as most bang methods, it means that it changes the object itself instead of only return a new object. Example on console:

```
> a = [1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
> a.slice(2,3)
 => [3] 
> a
 => [1, 2, 3] # didn't modified a
> a.slice!(2,3)
 => [3] 
> a
 => [1, 2]  # modified a
```

Second, don't use `while` to loop in a list. Simply use each (of course you can use it `do` and `end` if it is a multiline operation:

```
[1,2,3].each{|x| p x}
1
2
3
```

Third, the variables prefixed with double `@` should not be what you are thinking it is. They are not used often. I suggest you to read about it.

To see what went wrong with your date extraction logic, it is a good idea to open the ruby terminal (command is `irb`). Then type some lines, for example

```
> a_date = a_date.split("/").values_at(0)
 => ["11"] 
> a_date = a_date.slice!(3,2)
 => nil
```

I'm not correcting because I'm not 100% sure about what you wanted as output, but I think you can see the problem here now.

Happy hacking

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSV and date:

```
require 'csv'
require 'date'

date_and_account_number = []

CSV.foreach('data.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
    date_and_account_number << [row[3],row[1]]
end

date_and_account_number.map! {|e|  dt = DateTime.strptime(e[0],"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"); [dt.day,dt.month,dt.year,e[1]] }

#=> [[28, 11, 2007, "ar161429"], [9, 10, 2007, "ar182364"], [23, 10, 2007, "ar106644"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = <<_
id,account_number,balance,date
1,ar161429,482.29,11/28/2007 15:54
2,ar182364,266.93,10/9/2007 15:54
3,ar106644,887.78,10/23/2007 15:54
_

string.sub(/^.*$/, "").scan(%r{^[^,]*,([^,]*),[^,]*,([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(\S*)\s+.*$})
# => [
#      ["ar161429", "11", "28", "2007"],
#      ["ar182364", "10", "9", "2007"],
#      ["ar106644", "10", "23", "2007"]
#    ]
```